# What is the complexity of n/2 * log⁡(n^n)

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

I would like to know what is the Big O notation of n/2 * log⁡(n^n)
I'm trying to figure out if it's O(n/2 * log⁡(n^n)) just like that or is it O(n * log⁡(n^n)).

And how do I check it?

Comment: n^2 log(n), because log(n^n) = nlog(n)

Comment: I would say n^2 log(n)

Comment: You can omit the constant factors such as `1/2` in your case.

Comment: So to better understand what you are saying,
The time complexity of my function will not change when adding or removing some constant - in this example 1/2.
The Big O notation of this function will always be n* log⁡(n^n).